# Why am I told to "Connect to a power source" for best results when installing/updating software?

Tags: install, software-update, power, software, charge

I've experienced this when installing or updating a number of applications, most recently Logic Pro X. What's the reasoning behind this?

Answer (score 4):

It is recommended so that your MacBook battery does not die while installing updates, which may cause certain programs to break/become corrupted.

Comment: Why the down votes?